# pass a variable through the require_once()

Tags: php

I use this in my `index.php` to call page wanted

```
<?php require_once adROOT_K.'/pages/'.$page.'.php'; ?>
```

and  I have `tech_produit.php` page with pagination system

```
echo '<a href="index.php?page=tech_produit?nmpage=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
```

the warning is :

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

I do some search and I figure out that  require_once will open  the file called

`tech_produit?nmpage=2.php`

that's why I have error

Comment: yes, it does. and you should be veeeery careful with including $page into the filename, especially if it's some kind of user input. but for your problem: try to echo your complete file-path and check if the file actually exists - it seems like it doesn't

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i edit the my post,  required_once open file called tech_produit?nmpage=2.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake is : instead of using `&` I use by mistake  `?`

so I replace :

```
echo '<a href="index.php?page=tech_produit?nmpage=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
```

with :

```
echo '<a href="index.php?page=tech_produit&nmpage=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
```